# download a file with php and hash

Tags: php, file, download, hash, cloud-storage

So this is simple to understand what i want to achieve. So i get links like theese:

> http://rockdizfile.com/atfmzkm7236t
>
> http://rockdizfile.com/xuj5oincoqmy
>
> http://rockdizfile.com/pg8wg9ej3pou

So theese links are from one cloud storage site I want to make a php script that automates their downloading.

So I can't find which is the script or the thing these links download button starts and how can I start that so i can download it with php on my server?

Basically my idea is to download a lot of files but don't wanna do it manually so need automatic way of doing it. As far as I know I make a request which is the following 2 urls:

```
http://rockdizfile.com/pg8wg9ej3pou
http://wi32.rockdizfile.com/d/wsli6rbhfp4r2ge4t7cqeeztijrprelfiw4afvqg5iwspmvqabpkmgiz/Desislava%20feat.%20Mandi%20&%20Ustata%20-%20Pusni%20go%20pak%20(CDRIP).mp3
```

So the first url is executing the next one but here comes the tricky part as far as I tested that last string `Desislava%20feat.%20Mandi%20&%20Ustata%20-%20Pusni%20go%20pak%20(CDRIP).mp3` is the file name we get when downloading so if you change it with for example `somefile.mp3` it will download somefile.mp3 but with the same file content as `http://wi32.rockdizfile.com/d/wsli6rbhfp4r2ge4t7cqeeztijrprelfiw4afvqg5iwspmvqabpkmgiz/Desislava%20feat.%20Mandi%20&%20Ustata%20-%20Pusni%20go%20pak%20(CDRIP).mp3` so the data is hidden in this hash `wsli6rbhfp4r2ge4t7cqeeztijrprelfiw4afvqg5iwspmvqabpkmgiz` or i think so. And now is the tricky part how to get this hash? we have almost everything we have the code for the url  `atfmzkm7236t` the hash `wsli6rbhfp4r2ge4t7cqeeztijrprelfiw4afvqg5iwspmvqabpkmgiz` and the filename `Desislava%20feat.%20Mandi%20&%20Ustata%20-%20Pusni%20go%20pak%20(CDRIP).mp3` There must be a way to download from this site without clicking so please help me kinda a hack this :)

Comment: Unless you know the hash function, and what it's hashing (which I'm guessing you don't) then you stand no chance.
And even if you do it's a non-trivial problem (that what hash's are for)

Comment: The idea was what and which hash or encrypt function is used and maybe that is not so hard that was what i meant

Answer (score 0):

It's impossibly to tell you without the source code

e.g. sha1("Test Message") gives you 35ee8386410d41d14b3f779fc95f4695f4851682 but sha256("Vote this up") gives you 65e03c456bcc3d71dde6b28d441f5a933f6f0eaf6222e578612f2982759378ed

totally different... unless you're hidden function add's "65e03c456bcc3d71dde6b28dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" (where xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is a bunch of numbers I can't be arsed to work out) to each hash...
then sha1("Test Message") gives you 65e03c456bcc3d71dde6b28d441f5a933f6f0eaf6222e578612f2982759378ed

Comment: to search which database theese files are hosted externaly? The idea is not to make a user go to external site with adds and click the button so just click and it downloads

Comment: as far as i can tell there is 56 chars in the hash but i dont know a function which exports 56 char hash the funny thing is that hashes are different so first click there exports: http://wi31.rockdizfile.com/d/vslcv4jefp4r2ge4tlcrutlrifa7o4siqocp6ahvehqmulkcgzn4353o/Lil%20Eddie%20-%20Heaven.mp3 Second http://wi31.rockdizfile.com/d/vslcv4jefp4r2ge4tlcrutlrifa7o4siqocp6ahvehqmulkcgzhy4jip/Lil%20Eddie%20-%20Heaven.mp3


vslcv4jefp4r2ge4tlcrutlrifa7o4siqocp6ahvehqmulkcgzn4353o
vslcv4jefp4r2ge4tlcrutlrifa7o4siqocp6ahvehqmulkcgzhy4jip

Comment: Doesn't matter it could be the higher 28 bytes of two hash's one could be the file name and the other your IP address, or the month. you've no way of knowing.

Comment: That said SHA-224 generates a 56 Byte hash

Comment: yea but this request isn't with something like ajax so it will be coded in some javascript but when i see in chrome there is h9ztp1k3o6jv:1 so i have to go this link with port 1 ? but it isn't working file not found or that kind of error

Comment: I can't understand what scrape JS means ?

Comment: read the page into the program, then scan through the page until you find the hash, lift that hash and use that to make the call the to MP3 you want.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping

Comment: Man that was what i want to do the problem is how ? I cant understand where is that hash I found some program called MiPony which can download from this site

Answer (score 0):

you can use PHP's header function to force a file to download

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=index.php');
readfile('Link');
```

You should know that this will not give you the ability to download PHP files from external websites.

You can only use this if you got the direct link to a file

Comment: i know the link for the file which is http://rockdizfile.com/pg8wg9ej3pou and when i click on the download button i request this link http://wi32.rockdizfile.com/d/wsli6rbhfp4r2ge4t7cqeeztijrprelfiw4afvqg5iwspmvqabpkmgiz/Desislava%20feat.%20Mandi%20&%20Ustata%20-%20Pusni%20go%20pak%20(CDRIP).mp3 or link like this so my question is how to get from the first to the next link  or maybe somthing like makin php click a button and then capture the request and then send the request to the server and server to download it

Comment: Hmm, you will have to use some xpath to get source code of the webpage

Answer (score 0):

The file is embedded into the swf player.

```
alert(jwplayer('mp3player').config.file);
```

Something like:

```
<?PHP echo file_get_contents($_GET["url"]); ?>

<script>
document.location=jwplayer('mp3player').config.file;
</script>
```

Though I've actually just noticed they change 5 digits of the URL on each page request, and the script above uses 2 page requests. One to get the URL and HTML source and another to try and download the file, meaning the URL has changed before the second request has started.

Comment: How to make php open that player or something so i can alert the path or idk what